# How do you decode QByteArray sent by QTcpServer using python socket module?

Tags: python, tcp, protocols, pyqt5, python-3.3

Consider this code:

**client.py**

```
import socket
import json

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8000))
    s.send(json.dumps({'text': 'hello world'}).encode("utf-8"))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    print("received data:", data)
except Exception as e:
    print("-->", e)
```

**server.py**

```
import sys
import json

from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


class Server(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tcp_server = None

    def run(self):
        self.tcp_server = QTcpServer(self)
        if not self.tcp_server.listen(QHostAddress('127.0.0.1'), 8000):
            print("Can't listen!")
            self.close()
            return
        self.tcp_server.newConnection.connect(self.on_new_connection)

    def on_new_connection(self):
        client_connection = self.tcp_server.nextPendingConnection()
        client_connection.waitForReadyRead()
        message_dct = json.loads(
            client_connection.readAll().data().decode("utf-8"))
        print("received json:", message_dct)
        block = QByteArray()
        out = QDataStream(block, QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        out.writeString(json.dumps({'response': len(message_dct["text"])}).encode("utf-8"))
        client_connection.disconnected.connect(client_connection.deleteLater)
        client_connection.write(block)
        client_connection.disconnectFromHost()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    server = Server()
    server.run()
    sys.exit(server.exec_())
```

After running server.py and client.py, client.py will print:

```
received data: b'\x00\x00\x00\x11{"response": 11}\x00'
```

I don't understand what's the meaning of the extra bytes around the dictionary (the initial 4 bytes `\x00\x00\x00\x11`) and the last one (`\x00`), do they represent TCP metadata information added by QTcpServer?

Anyway, I'd like to know what's the proper way to decode the dictionary on client.py so you'll get the dictionary `{"response": 11}`

NS: client.py is intended to run on a python3.3.6 python process where the easiest way to go is by using the standard library (ie: using twisted or external deps is tricky), also... asyncio is not available...  that's why I'm using the good old `socket` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QDataStream` is a class that is responsible for serializing and realizing various types of data, so it requires sending additional information such as the size of the information.

Going to your message:

```
json.dumps({'response': len(message_dct["text"])})
```

is

```
{"response": 11}
```

which is a string, and you to convert it to bytes with `encode("utf-8")`, showing the character `0x00` indicating the end of the character:

```
0x7B 0x22 0x72 0x65 0x73 0x70 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x65 0x22 0x3A 0x20 0x31 0x31 0x7D 0x00
```

So the length of the information is 17 bytes which in hexadecimal is `0x11`.

`QDataStream` when sending the data will indicate with 4 bytes the size of the data, therefore we observe the first 4 bytes that numerically is 11:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11{"response": 11}\x00'
[     length     ][       data       ]
```

For the above we already understand the behavior.

so there are 2 solutions:

1. Decode the data with `QDataStream` on the client side, but as you indicate you have limitations of the packages you can use.
2. Not use QDataStream and send the bytes directly.

   ```
   def on_new_connection(self):
       client_connection = self.tcp_server.nextPendingConnection()
       client_connection.waitForReadyRead()
       message_dct = json.loads(
           client_connection.readAll().data().decode("utf-8"))
       print("received json:", message_dct)
       block = json.dumps({'response': len(message_dct["text"])}).encode("utf-8")
       client_connection.disconnected.connect(client_connection.deleteLater)
       client_connection.write(block)
       client_connection.disconnectFromHost()
   ```

Comment: Really nice answer, I hadn't read the docs about write (QTcpSocket<-QIODevice) and for some strange reason I was "assuming" you was forced to use QDataStream. Tyvm!